# Reading image metadata from web URL

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, metadata

Been looking around and can't find a definite way to do this...
I need to read the meta data from an image found at a certain URL. Is there a way to do this on the iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using iphone-exif and it just wasn't working in my project. Saw a lot of people getting the same errors as me.

Good news is I found another solution...

```
    NSDictionary *IPTCDict;

    NSString *urlString = @"http://SOMEIMAGEURL.jpg";
    NSMutableData *photoData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)photoData, NULL);
    NSDictionary *metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
    NSLog(@"Meta: %@", metadata);  //Will print out all the metadata

    // Pulls out the IPTC data
    IPTCDict = [metadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary];

    NSLog(@"Caption: %@\nCopyright: %@", [IPTCDict objectForKey:@"Caption/Abstract"],      [IPTCDict objectForKey:@"CopyrightNotice"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-answer:

Try this: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/

You should be able to fetch the image properties (metadata). Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm looking to do this locally through xcode though... I will be receiving image URLs from a web service and want to read the metadata behind them

Comment: Looking at iphone-exif, I think it should work for you, Eric. You said "locally through xcode" - the library has to be built and added to your project. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/downloads/detail?name=iphone-exif-guide-0.8.pdf. A UIImage has to be created by retrieving the URL and then you can use the library to get the EXIF data. Or were you hoping to just retrieve the EXIF Data and not get the whole file data from the server?